# Is Breacher wearing a European style necktie to point to Schwarzenegger's heritage?

Tags: props, sabotage

In [Sabotage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1742334/) (2014) the character Breacher, played by Arnold Schwarzenegger, is shown wearing a European style necktie, i.e. the stripes showing positive diagonals when seen by others ( // , see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necktie#Ties_as_a_sign_of_membership)). If I didn't miss anyone all the other characters wear neckties in the US American style (stripes showing negative diagonals \\ ) which is to be expected as the characters are all US Americans. This is best visible in the beginning in the taped interrogation scene. The shots change between Breacher and the interrogation team.

Was this done on purpose to point out Schwarzenegger's European (specifically Austrian) heritage? I guess he didn't bring or selected his own props; and even if so I guess he lives long enough in the US (and he was even quite engaged in his community there) so not much of his original wardrobe has survived.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know such a thing existed. +1 for imparting new knowledge.

Comment: Wut? There *is* even such a thing like a difference in diagonal direction of ties? Most subtle cultural difference for me since *Inglorious Basterds*'s finger counting style. Yet *if* done conciously it might make a difference if his *character* is supposed to be purely American or not. In the former case it would just be an easter egg about *Arnie* himself and in the latter case a proper character hint. But interesting question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't remember anything hinting to a non US background of that character.

Comment: @his: Judging by the comments here thus far, it's very possible the film makers didn't know the difference either lol!

Comment: Not sure why someone who has held office in the US would go out of their way to remind people, even subtly, of their Austrian heritage. Perhaps the filmmakers *(or just the wardrobe department)* did it intentionally and Arnold didn't even know about it? Not to sound like a conspiracy nut, but it's a possibility.

Comment: his - Why do you call them negative and positive diagonals?  I am not familiar with those terms.  In heraldry a negative diagonal pattern would be called bendy and a positive diagonal pattern would be called bendy sinister.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_(heraldry)